# jdbc-outbound-gateway async error handling in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to implement a fire-and-forget flow to log messages on a database by calling an Oracle procedure, everything works fine but I'd like to log any exception I get when, by any chance, I misconfigured the xml or whatever else could go wrong (any exception thrown by the procedure?).
I've searched for quite some time but I'm probably missing out something...

Here's the actual setting:
I've got a gateway interface

```
public interface gatewayInterfaceDEF{
    void monitoring(Object payload);
}
```

XML definition of the gateway

```
<int:gateway service-interface="gatewayInterfaceDEF">
        <int:method name="monitoring" request-channel="monitoringGatewayInbound" />
</int:gateway>
```

Then the JDBC-outbound-gateway xml configuration that calls an oracle procedure:

```
<int:channel id="monitoringGatewayInbound">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="monitoringTaskExecutor"/>
</int:channel>

<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
    id="monitoringGatewayProcedure" request-channel="monitoringGatewayInbound"
    data-source="dataSource" stored-procedure-name="procedureName"
    return-value-required="false" ignore-column-meta-data="true">
    <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition
        someparameters />
    <int-jdbc:parameter parameter mapping />
</int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
```

Thanks in advance

I've found this: http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-async-and-exception
But it's not working: could it be me not being able to implement it, but still.

UPDATE: the wrapped log I get.

```
|TEST|2014-10-17 17:09:08,999|||059EF53A6C4D2F67E0540003BA7A7C43|[monitoringTaskExecutor-1]|INFO |STDOUT|17:09:08,999 ERROR [LoggingHandler] org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.jdbc.StoredProcOutboundGateway#0]
```

UPDATE2: the jboss-log4j.xml I'm using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="STDFILE" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="true" />
        <param name="file" value="/var/share/test/logs/test-ws_out.log" />
        <param name="datePattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="TEST|%d|%X{req.remoteHost}|%X{sessionid}|%X{lcontext}|[%t]|%-5p|%c|%m%n|" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDFILE" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: Good. Thanks for logs. Now show, please, your logger config. It's interesting how your categories are configured. And share, please, an info in which environment you are: Tomcat, WebSphere etc.

Comment: Sorry I was on mobile and I didn't manage to format it.
I'm updating the log4j now and I'm using the JBoss one, in its folder.
(To find that log I had to use a default one).

I'll be outside the workplace till monday, so I'm not sure if I'll be able to answer properly...
(I'm deploying on JBoss 5.1 If I remember correctly)

Comment: we are using spring-integration version 3.0.2 and spring 3.1.8.
Any news?

Comment: It doesn't matter. I think the root of issue is somewhere in the JBOSS, as it catches all logs and print them under that category.

Comment: You were right: we deployed on WebLogic and the error is now showing with the proper severity.

Thank you very much Artem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `ExcutorChannel`, any `Exception` from the downstream flow is wrapped to the `ErrorMessage` and sent to the default `errorChannel`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler

By default all those exceptions are looged by `LoggingHandler` under category `org.springframework.integration.handler` with `ERROR` level.

From other side you can add `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` to the `<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice

And get deal with exception just only on that target `MessageHandler`

Comment: I got why... it's because the error message gets wrapped like this: |TEST|2014-10-17 17:09:08,999|||059EF53A6C4D2F67E0540003BA7A7C43|[monitoringTaskExecutor-1]|INFO |STDOUT|17:09:08,999 ERROR [LoggingHandler] org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.jdbc.StoredProcOutboundGateway#0] Is it intended?

Comment: H-m... It's something up to your logging system, not to the Spring Integration.

Comment: I'll look into it but that log comes from the spring task executor... am I wrong? Looks like the task executor wraps it with an info log

Comment: Show, please the log snippet in your question. I haven't gotten it yet

Comment: Updated with the wrapped log I get.